# Is it possible to rerender pageblockSection located inside child apex:component?

Tags: visualforce, rerender, parent-to-child

I wonder if it is possible to rerender pageblockSection that is nested inside child apex:component. I noticed that rerender whole child visualforce component need wrapping it within some outputPanel but what can I do when it is not possible to do that?

Comment: It's not possible to do so reliably, as far as I recall, because of how the ID values end up getting calculated. You'd have better luck not trying to do this.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. So, component should be nested inside pageblockSection and probably it wiłl be possible to rerender them?

Comment: does the `apex:component` have its own custom controller?

Comment: Yes it have its own custom controller @cropredy

Comment: so, can you use apex properties on the custom controller to control the pageblockSection `rendered=` ?

Comment: @cropredy - Yes I can use apex properties on the custom controller but I need `rerender`.

Comment: If the changed value gets posted to the component controller, then the rerender operation will exploit the current controller property values